# In need of help for a transitive property for inequalities!

Tags: calculus, inequality

Need help in determining if $\frac{1}{1+x}$ is larger or smaller than $\frac{1}{x+\sin^2 x}$ for $x \geq 1$.

My reasoning for this question being up is that I don't see too many transitive property for inequalities questions on the site!

Comment: Welcome to MSE! What have you tried? In case you need a little help getting started, here's a hint: $\sin^2(x) \le 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\cos^2(x)\geq 0$$

$$\cos^2(x)+\sin^2(x)\geq \sin^2(x)$$

$$1\geq \sin^2(x)$$

$$1+x\geq \sin^2(x)+x$$

$$\frac{1}{1+x} \leq \frac{1}{\sin^2(x)+x}$$

Comment: The bound $\sin^2(x) \leq 1$ can be obtained more directly: it follows from $|\sin(x)| \leq 1$, which, in turn, follows from the definition of sine.  Still, your derivation is perfectly valid.

Comment: Thank you so much! Also, what is the process called when you put both parts under 1 and flipped the greater than or equal to sign?

Comment: Note that reversing the order of the inequality after reciprocation is only valid if both quantities are of the same sign.

Comment: I don't know the official name, but I've heard it been called "flipping the inequality", it's basically just division. Pay special attention to @hardmath's comment as well

Answer (score 2):

Take the difference and study the resulting function:
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{1+x} - \frac{1}{x + \sin^{2}(x)} & = \frac{(x+\sin^{2}(x)) - (1+x)}{(1+x)(x+\sin^{2}(x))}\\\\
& = \frac{\sin^{2}(x) - 1}{(1+x)(x+\sin^{2}(x))} \leq 0
\end{align*}